# `torch.conj_physical` faster than `torch.conj` if full output is used?

Tags: python, performance, pytorch, lazy-evaluation

[conj](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.conj.html) docs

> `torch.conj()` performs a lazy conjugation, but the actual conjugated tensor can be materialized at any time using `torch.resolve_conj()`

[conj_physical](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.conj_physical.html) docs

> This performs the conjugate operation regardless of the fact conjugate bit is set or not.

So I figure, if we're guaranteed to access/modify the entire output, then latter can't be any slower than former, and should sometimes be faster. In benchmarking, I define

```py
def fn0(x):
    o = torch.conj(x)
    o += 1j

def fn1(x):
    o = torch.conj_physical(x)
    o = += 1j
```

and here `fn1` is definitively faster, 5-50% across CPU & GPU. But replacing the second line with `torch.mean(o)` or other common operations, the difference is insignificant (`fn1` is still a little ahead). Replacing with `o *= x` still reproduces the speedup, so it seems to concern in-place operations.

Is `torch.conj` ever faster than `conj_physical` if we're accessing/modifying the entire output? And optionally, why the difference with in-place vs not? *(torch 2.0.1, Python 3.11.4, Windows 11)*

#### Full bench script

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import torch
import torch.utils.benchmark as benchmark

# Define funcs ###############################################################
def fn0(x):
    o = torch.conj(x)
    o += 1j

def fn1(x):
    o = torch.conj_physical(x)
    o += 1j

# Make bench funcs ###########################################################
names = ('fn0', 'fn1')
n_iters = 2000
n_iters_gpu = n_iters * 100
got_gpu = bool(torch.cuda.is_available())


#%% Benchmark ################################################################
times = {}
for N in (10000, 100000, 1000000):
    x = torch.randn(N, dtype=torch.complex64)
    x_gpu = x.cuda()

    times[N] = {}
    for name in names:
        common = dict(stmt=f'{name}(x)', setup=f'from __main__ import {name}')
        # cpu ----------------------------------------------------------------
        key = name
        bench_fn = benchmark.Timer(**common, globals={'x': x})
        # warmup
        _ = bench_fn.timeit(3)
        # bench
        times[N][key] = bench_fn.timeit(n_iters).mean

        # gpu ----------------------------------------------------------------
        if got_gpu:
            key = name + '-gpu'
            # warmup
            bench_fn = benchmark.Timer(**common, globals={'x': x_gpu})
            # warmup
            _ = bench_fn.timeit(300)
            # bench
            times[N][key] = bench_fn.timeit(n_iters_gpu).mean

        # "progress bar"
        print(end='.', flush=True)

#%% Print results ############################################################
print()
for N in times:
    print(f"N={N}")
    for name in names:
        print(name + '-cpu', "%.3g" % times[N][name])
    if got_gpu:
        for name in names:
            print(name + '-gpu', "%.3g" % times[N][name + '-gpu'])
    print()
```